# ucrtbase.dll is causing Qgis to crash

Tags: python, qgis, or-tools

I have a QGis plugin to solve a vehicle routing problem using ORTools.

When the program gets to the ORTools part, Qgis crashes and leaves an Error Event in Eventviewer, but no stacktrace.

According to this event the crash is caused by ucrtbase.dll. See the screenshot below.

The OS is Windows server 2012 with latest updates.

I have created the user mode crash dump which is uploaded to onedrive including the WER report file here:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApOUFM1sYj1FhRT5NvmpmrWYYWum

[event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UI5i.jpg)

Comment: Please post the text of the error message (and maybe an excerpt from any logs). Your link points to an executable and a zip file and not to a screen shot.

Comment: Hi, the event viewer screenshot you can find by clicking onto "event". Both of the 2 files on the link above should be zip files, not executables. The one which has qgis.exe in the name is the user mode crash dump, the other one is the wer log file.